# Python print to same line during loop

Tags: python, printing, terminal

I have the following loop which prints a period after each iteration:

```
for i in range(3):
    time.sleep(1)
    print('.')
```

This runs exactly as expected: a period is printed to the terminal on a new line in 1 second increments

```
.  # after 1 seconds
.  # after 2 seconds
.  # after 3 seconds
```

I want to change the output to print periods to the same line (so the output is more compact and easier to read). However, I have a problem when I change the code to the following:

```
for i in range(3):
    time.sleep(1)
    print('.', end='')
```

In this case, the single line of periods only print all at once when the for loop is complete:

```
...  # all after 3 seconds
```

Am I doing something wrong here or there a limitation with the python `print` statement?

Comment: This is because `print` by default operate on each line, if you want it to generate dynamic content like `.`, then `..`. You'll need to use `sys.stdout.flush()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, terminal output won't appear until a newline is printed.

You can force partial lines to appear immediately by adding `flush=True` to the print call.

Comment: And in case of Python 2, `sys.stdout.flush()`

Answer (score 0):

Here, this will help you:

```
import time

for i in range(3):
    time.sleep(1)
    print(".", end="", flush=True)
print("")
```

**Edit**

In case you are using python2, be sure to add

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

as the first statement to your script.